# Extending holomorphic functions of several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $M$ be a complex manifold, and let $f : M \to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function which is holomorphic everywhere but on a closed hypersurface $H \subset M$. Can I deduce that $f$ is holomorphic on all of $M$?

Of course, if $M$ is a Riemann surface, then $H$ is a bunch of isolated points, so the Riemann extension theorem applies. But what about the higher-dimensional case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  The Weyl lemma says that every distributional solution to the CR equations is actually a holomorphic function.  Your $f$ definitely qualifies.